# How to plan to avoid combat deaths for NPCs that aren't obvious railroads?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encounter-design

I am playing a Pathfinder campaign based on the Beginner Box materials. The party were relatively diplomatic in the first adventure and didn't fight and kill the goblin boss King Fatmouth in Black Fang's dungeon, so I will have him return leading another band of goblins.

As well as specific equipment/strategies to escape (e.g. smoke bombs), what are some less obvious ways (particularly improvising equipment or the environment) to, as a GM, plan for an NPC villain to avoid dying in a combat or leave their fate ambiguous?

Comment: It looks like your goblin boss already escaped the first raid so... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm reminded of the surrender tactics of Splug in Keep on the Shadowfell.

Comment: @zachiel if the group warm to him as a character, I would like to have the option to have him as a recurring NPC for the campaign.

Comment: Do you want to be within the rules or are you going to wave your hands and come up with an excuse?

Comment: @okeefe, within the rules. A deus ex machina would be jarring. I'd like to know some tricks to prevent me from having to GM fiat or obviously railroad the survival.

Comment: So you're not so much looking for suggestions for contingency plans and escape routes, you're looking more for in-combat powers, magic items, and combos that enable a reliable escapes? So less "build a secret backdoor in his base" and more "equip him with Pellets of Sudden Obscurative Smoke and Boots of Retreating-ness" kind of thing?

Comment: @sevensideddie yes, but smoke bombs are seem like something you'd have specifically so that you could escape. A piece of equipment that could be appropriated into an escape/combat disrupting tool. If the piece of kit is a bit esoteric, a reason to have it, e.g. dynamite for mining.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question. Your question title says, "What are ... combat escape plans for NPCs?", yet in your comment you say, "... but smoke bombs seem like something you'd have specifically so that you could escape." It's not really clear to me what you are asking for here, given that comment.

Comment: Keep in mind that people may actually *plan* to escape combat? As in, "I should keep this in case I get attacked by big bad adventurers!" style.

Comment: Closed at the OP's request.  Not sure why, this only requires a little editing to be a very good question - we've all wanted our bad guys to "get away" and a question on techniques to that end it valid, it just needs to be stated in clear language.

Comment: @mxyzplk [This was the conversation in chat about it.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/conversation-about-stuperusers-question) (note that there's another conversation going on at the same time between BESW and Holland, though BESW also participates in this one)

Comment: Eh, avoiding a list question is 70% on the answerers to answer with techniques instead of being lazy and answering with point implementations of techniques. Maybe I'll edit and reopen sometime when I'm bored.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of goblins, I'd go with traps. A trapped lair provides hazards for adventurers, but it also allows the cunning inventor a chance to make escape routes and cave-ins designed to obscure his escape under the pretense of a deadly trap. There are a whole bunch of ways that he could fake his death, but what the PCs don't know is that there's hay at the bottom of the pit.